# Mysqli query returns no rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For whatever reason, I keep getting the `echo "No News.";` even though I clearly have information put into the table which is named `news`.

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
define('DB_USER', "USERNAME");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "PASSWORD");
define('DB_DATABASE', "DATABASE");


$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Email Owner@OtherTXT.com";
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */

$query = "SELECT `title`, `message`, `date` FROM `news`";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h2>";
        echo ($row["title"]);
        echo "</h2>";
        echo "<h3>";
        echo ($row["date"]);
        echo "</h3>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<p>";
        echo ($row["message"]);
        echo "</p>";

    }
} else {
    echo "No News.";
}


$mysqli->close();
?>
```

This is a picture of my table

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7xZTSvd.png]

Comment: Can you please run SELECT `title`, `message`, `date` FROM `news` query in your phpmyadmin query window and check whats the result is coming..

Comment: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT title,message,date FROM `news`");`

Comment: @Developer ,  irrelevant comment...

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar when I run `SELECT `title`, `message`, `date` FROM `news`` I get the correct rows listed

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help ;)

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h2>";
        echo ($row["title"]);
        echo "</h2>";
        echo "<h3>";
        echo ($row["date"]);
        echo "</h3>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<p>";
        echo ($row["message"]);
        echo "</p>";

    }
} else {
    echo "No News.";
}
```

Comment: I feel like I must have done something wrong, I still get the echo that says No News. =/
http://pastebin.com/htwGDrtm

Answer (score -1):

Maybe adding a *store_result* before calling the num rows do the trick:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$result->store_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
...
```

Or you can put it into the query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```

Comment: I added in the `store_result` and I get this error, "Fatal error: Call to a member function store_result() on a non-object in news.php on line 21"

Comment: Hmm if you echo `$result`, which *resource* it returns?